# Applying OOP in small open source project

Tags: php, oop, object

So my current understanding of classes are:
Singleton for a class that will only ever be instantiated once.
Static for a class that doesn't get instantiated but just exists.
Regular? For a class that can get instantiated over and over.

So I'm doing a small open source project and as for dealing with users, I thought of how I could deal with it, for example:
Creating a user - I could instantiate a users object and then call a method create on it. Or I could have a singleton so the users object always exists and call create on that?

I just think it seems sort of sloppy to create an object for each user related action, like updating a users credentials, would I want to instantiate another user object and then call a method update on it?

Just confused about how to actually apply OOP, and the best way to do.

Thanks for any/all help you guys can provide.

Comment: Class/Static methods that return instances of that (or a related) model/object are called "Factories".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it's a small project I'd recommend looking at the available PHP frameworks. [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) leaves a small footprint and embraces fast deployment.

For this case, if we leave out the possible usage of frameworks I'd go with a User class that would look something like this:

```
class User{
    private $user = array();

    public function __construct($user_id = 0){
        if($user_id !== 0){
            $this->user = $this->get($user_id);
        }
    }

    public function get($user_id){
        // .. code
    }

    public function update($data, $user_id = 0){
        if($user_id == 0){
            $user_id = $this->user['user_id'];
        }

        // .. code
    }

    public function create($data){
        // .. code
    }

    public function delete($user_id){
        // .. code
    }
}
```

Comment: As for CI, I've developed with it before, and love it's rapid development. However this was sort of my own undertaking where I want things to be entirely custom.

As for your class, yes I understand the concept, I was just looking if that was the best way to do it, creating a new user object every time I wanted to modify a user, or better yet, how would I go about it when trying to get all users from the database?

Comment: You could write a more general purpose class and initiate the user object when the application starts. For example a class containing the methods: `get()`, `get_all()`, `update()`, `create()` and `delete()`.